# Operator precedence ' ++ ' JavaScript

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence, post-increment

found an incomprehensible case for myself in some examples on  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

There is example:

```
function isPrime(element, index, array) {
  var start = 2;
  while (start <= Math.sqrt(element)) {
    if (element % start++ < 1)** {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return element > 1;
}
```

My test input:  console.log([ 8, 12, 7 ].find(isPrime))

So the qustion is why **(element % start++ < 1)** is **true** when element is 8, i checked operator precedence and increment '++' has a higher priority than  '%' , ==> 8 % 3 = 1 - should be false

Comment: Consider using `++start` instead.

Comment: `++` has a higher precedence but `x++` would still return the value of `x` *before* incrementing.

Comment: [Cheat sheet for pre-/post- incrementation](https://jsbin.com/jovijey/1/edit?js,console)